# Oracle APEX Users table

Tags: oracle-apex

It possible to move application *users* to my table for management? And where I can find this table (*users*) or other tables, for example *apex_activity_log*?
I was tried to create *Authentication Scheme* in *Authentication Schemes*, but it doesn't creates tables in my database.

Application Express 20.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. This table is part of administration tables and gets installed when you run @apexins.sql

It does get created in same database where you are installing APEX.
Refer to below link for details on installation(I found useful):
https://mikesmithers.wordpress.com/2019/03/01/installing-apex-and-ords-on-oracle-18cxe-on-centos/

Comment: thank you. It's possible to create users table myself and use it for users authorization?

Comment: I have solved this problem. I have created Users table and Authentication Scheme.

Comment: Yes it is... I see you have already created. hopefully it will solve your problem.